# .htaccess protected HTML5 videos not playing

Tags: security, video, stock-browser, html5

I have videos in a directory which is protected through .htaccess. I want to deliver the videos by means of the `<video>` tag.

Here is an example:
[protected video](http://www.unet.univie.ac.at/~a0403694/protected/)

Use test/test to login.

Without the protection the same video plays fine:
[unprotected video](http://www.unet.univie.ac.at/~a0403694/unprotected/)

I've tried it with the stock browser and also Chrome.
I am on a custom 4.0.4 ROM.

Am I the only one experiencing this issue? I couldn't find anything on Android's Bug Tracker.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Firefox on Ubuntu either. I get "no video with supported file format and MIME type found". I don't think this is an Android problem.

Comment: Works for me on Firefox 28 on Windows 8.
On Chrome on my Phone, it seems to keep loading indefinitely... Same on stock browser (4.1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The bug has been fixed** in one of the latest Chrome Beta versions.

Here is the reference:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/20bd0b28f6467339e611311aaf241d7eab388578
https://codereview.chromium.org/405663002

------------------- my original answer below --------------------

The problem also persists on Android 4.3 and most probably also with later versions.

I've reported the issue on chromium's bug tracker and it has been confirmed:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331876

There's also a bug report on the Android's bug tracker for the stock browser:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43414

I hope this issue will get fixed soon.

Comment: This bug is still present.
Actually it's present in all Android browsers except Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Both worked fine for me in Google Chrome.

I am using Mac Book Pro with OS X Maverick and the latest version of Google Chrome.
On firefox ( latest version) it displays an error:

```
No video with supported format and MIME type found.
```

On safari it keeps loading. See the screen shot please.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was talking about Android. I thought it would be clear. Firefox doesn't support .mp4 h.264 videos yet, except on Windows.

Comment: Hello, No problem. I know you are taking about Android, I have just tried to check it in my computer to see if it works in there. I thought it might be a little information to help you with this. : )